# Delete Azure Blob contents before copy

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage

I’m creating an Azure pipeline that does the following:

- Gets last artifact
- Copies that artifact to an azure container

This works but I need to delete everything in the container before copying. Those files are in subfolders but have this issue:

Azure file copy v5 gets a blob prefix error so i cant use the cleanup files. So had to drop to v3 and not sure where to go from here

Used v5 but receive the error upload to container with blob prefix failed with error azcopy.exe

Comment: Share your pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are facing issue with `Azure File Copy v5` and the blob prefix error when trying to delete files in `Azure container,` you can try another approach using the `Azure CLI` task in your Azure pipeline.

You can use the `azcopy remove` command with the `--recursive` command in order to delete all files in a container in `Azure Blob Storage`.

`Azure CLI` task with  `azcopy remove` command in your script to delete all files in the container.

Here is an example command to delete all blobs in a container using `azcopy remove`

```
azcopy remove "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/*" --recursive
```

**Remove Task:**

```yaml
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '<Azure subscription>'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          azcopy remove "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>/*" --recursive
```

[image]

3. Once all files are deleted in container, you can proceed with the **Azure File** [**Copy**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) task to copy the new artifact to the Azure container.

```
azcopy copy "<path-to-artifact>" "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>" --recursive --delete-destination
```

**Copy Task:**

```yaml
    - task: AzureCLI@2
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '<Azure subscription>'
            scriptType: 'bash'
            scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
            inlineScript: |
            azcopy copy "<path-to-artifact>" "https://<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container-name>" --recursive --delete-destination
```